# Teamcity - deploying to virtual application "ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED" error

Tags: iis, teamcity

I have a website that also has a virtual application (separate project) at the root.

I am trying to deploy to the virtual application using Teamcity.  However, I keep receiving the following error:

"More Information: Connected to the remote computer ("xxxk") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED."

I know the credentials are correct, the site does exist and the users have all the correct credentials.  I have tried everything on the "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED" link.

I get the feeling that its just not possible to deploy to a virtual application.  Has anyone managed to successfully deploy to a virtual application before?

Thanks in advance.

Adam

Comment: How are you trying to deploy the virtual application?  What type of build runner are you using?

Comment: @tspauld I have 3 build steps within teamcity - 1) MSBuild, 2) Recycle App pool, 3) Deploy package to server.  The deploy build step uses the command line runner.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  Having the same issue